# Google App Engine simple app is created and working on local. But i am unable to deploy to App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google App Engine  simple app is created and working on local. But i am unable to deploy to App Engine

But i am getting following error

> Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.
>
> See the deployment console for more details
> Unable to update app: Failed to compile jsp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that there is a compilation problem for one or more of your JSPs. Observe the error in the Eclipse Console view and you will be able to see which of the JSPs did not compile. It will also point to an error log file that you can view to see the same compilation errors.

The reason that it is working on local could be due to you not executing any of those problematic JSPs, so it might just look like there is no problem.

Another issue could be that you have the JRE and not JDK setup in your Eclipse, as a result of which it is not able to compile.

Comment: I am basically a .net developer. And i am quite new to java , i think you are correct "issue could be that you have the JRE and not JDK setup in your Eclipse, as a result of which it is not able to compile" . How can i set up JDK in eclipse

Comment: Thanks Romin. I have setup JDK in Eclipse and now its working fine.
[setup JDK](http://techiedan.com/2009/10/19/set-up-jdk-in-eclipse/)

Comment: OK Great. I was about to put the instructions :-). Glad that it is all working now.